# Simple input/output applet with text boxes

Tags: java, text, applet

I have a console application that uses `System.out.println`'s to output text. What I want to do is turn it into an applet, where instead of `System.out.println`'s, it displays the text in a text box. Is there a relatively easy way to convert this?

Comment: Why an applet?  You need a HTTP server to run a web applet.  Perhaps you mean a JFrame, which you can run as an application.

Comment: Shameless plug: There is a project, [DragonConsole](http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/) that offers a Swing Component that acts like a console. You can print to it or review the source code to see how I did it. **Note** I've never tested in an Applet environment so I'm not sure if the project will work as an Applet - but again, the source is there for you if you want to look at it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have an HTTP server. Basically I want to embed my console application into a web page. The only way I figured I could do this is by turning it into an applet.

Answer (score 2):

[Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) is a simple class that will allow you to redirect ouput to a JTextArea or JTextPane.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a relatively easy way to convert this?

Sure, all you need to do is create an applet<sup>1</sup> and add a single JTextArea<sup>2</sup> to it. And then instead of your `System.out.println(str)`'s, you do `textArea.setText(str)` (or `textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + str)` to append text)

1. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/
2. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

#### EDIT

And to get user input, checkout the `showInputDialog` method from the `JOptionPane` class. Examples can be found here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Great! I also use Scanners in my application, is there an easy way to convert them to text fields for user input?